# Changing cranks from Praxis to Ultegra (BB advice)

Tags: crankset, bottom-bracket, power

I purchased a Specialized Roubaix Comp 2018 last year, I was not intending to purchase this bike but Evans had a 40% off sale and the deal was too outrageous to pass. I was originally looking at bikes with Shimano 105 groupset because I was given a friend's old stages 105 left hand side power meter. This power meter has been sitting around for months and months. I recently got an indoor trainer and have started 'properly' training. Reading power has been a big step up in my understanding of pacing and I'm very keen to get a power meter on the bike for when I'm out and about (once the world lets us out of lockdown...).

My problem is that I have no idea if my bike will take an Ultegra crankset. The currently fitted crank is a `Praxis Zayante`. The bottom bracket is not explicitly stated, most sites say "Included w/ crankset" (source: [specialized](https://www.specializedconceptstore.co.uk/product/12184/2018-roubaix-comp/)).

Looking on the bike itself, the BB has external cups and say M30, so it looks like the BB is the [M30 THRU BSA Threaded](https://praxiscycles.com/product/m30-thru-bsa_threaded/).

Now I understand very little about bottom bracket standards and honestly reading about them has confused the situation for me more...

Do I simply just unscrew the Praxis and fit a Shimano Ultegra BB such as the [6800](https://www.chainreactioncycles.com/shimano-ultegra-6800-bottom-bracket/rp-prod108701)?

Will my frame fit a different bottom bracket? I could not find any numbers for my frames BB sizing. Do these bikes adopt a standard or are they all slightly (stupidly) different?

The Shimano BB looks very cheap, this is a luxury/performance bike and I'd expect such a crucial part to cost a little more, are there better (less creaky) options than the vanilla BB for not much more?

*Authors note: I recognise an Ultegra crank with 105 LHS is scuffed but cheaper than getting a 4iii for my Praxis (which is seemingly unavailable)*

---

Edit: Here is a picture of the external cup on the LHS

[image: Picture of the bottom bracket on the LHS]

Comment: Didn't mention in the question but I will most definitely get a trusted shop to do the work. I draw the line at the disc brakes!

Comment: Actually crank and threaded BB removal.installation is one of the easier bike maintenance jobs

Comment: Just a point of information: this Specialized model may have a PF30 or BB30 BB. If so, the OP needs to source a PF30 or BB30 unit that either takes a 24mm spindle natively, or that takes a 30mm crank spindle and then get adapters for the Shimano spindle. https://www.theproscloset.com/blogs/news/specialized-roubaix-vs-trek-domane#bb

Comment: @WeiwenNg very good find, however that page does say the 2018 model year could be either standard?! So, useful but I'm still not 100% sure what OP has, I've updated my answer a little more. Sorry for the chopping around Axemasta, BBs can get complicated, but once you know what you have, and what you want, the solution will reveal itself

Comment: @Swifty thank you so much for the detailed answers! incredibly informative :)

Comment: *Authors note: I recognise an Ultegra crank with 105 LHS*  Unless you're into spending quite a bit of extra money to save a few grams, just get a 105 crank to match your LHS.  It'll work just as well, be cheaper, and both sides will match.

Comment: The rest of the bike is an ultegra groupset, forgive me for being really anal but I really want to have that sleek, all ultegra look to the bike. Eventually the plan is to pickup a used ultegra and chuck out the 105. This is a completely stupid and wasteful thing to do, but it just looks so nice! :p

Comment: I'm also looking into buying a dedicated gravel bike for winter since I've had alot of problems with corrosion on my bike whilst riding throughout winter (despite my best efforts to hose it down and clean it intensely every ~50 miles). I'll probably buy the original bike i wanted, a trek checkpoint alr 5 and put it on that!

Answer (score 4):

If it is an M30 Thru BSA, then the cups will say 'M30 THRU'. As they say M30 and only M30 then they are the [M30 BSA](https://praxiscycles.com/product/m30-english-threaded/) version. The latter suits crank spindles which are 30mm drive side, 28mm non-drive side, as the [Zayante crank is](https://praxiscycles.com/product/zayante/).

If they say anything else (like press fit) then (future readers) can match that to other models on the Praxis website before proceeding. For example, it's possible to get [thread-together units for pressfit frames](https://praxiscycles.com/product/m30-conv-bb30-pf30/) which don't look that different but have different wording on and are not BSA.

If BSA is confirmed, then the frame is threaded to the BSA standard. As the Shimano spindle is a smaller diameter (24mm) then yes you would need to change the bottom bracket, but this is trivial with a BSA threaded frame. That is to say, yes you unscrew the Praxis and screw in a Shimano.

It does look like the Praxis BB may require a different tool to the Hollowtech II items, but the shop can check this and take care of it, maybe make them aware beforehand to avoid delay if they need to get a tool in. I think having the shop do the whole job is a fair idea, it represents minimal risk to your wallet, even if parts are more expensive at retail.

Happily you can mix and match the Shimano BB, new chainset and 105 LH crank.

I know of no reason to distrust Shimano BBs; the more expensive ones are lighter and smaller items which might make them look less 'rugged' perhaps, but they are tailored to perform a certain way, i.e. light and racy.

---

*If* the bottom bracket cups say anything additional to "M30" then it is a different model.  As Weiwen Ng has sleuthed in a comment above, it seems 2018 Roubaixses may have either BSA threaded, or pressfit bottom brackets, so measure twice, order once if reading this in the future.

Comment: I don't have a carbon Specialized (and I believe the OP's bike is carbon), but it seems unlikely that the BB is English threaded (BSA). I'm honestly not sure what BB the OP has. Specialized's Oversized BB (OSBB) standard may be a synonym for PF30 or BB30, however.

Comment: @WeiwenNg thanks, I did a little more digging and have updated

Comment: I believe Praxis M30 is their proprietary standard (crank spindle is 30mm/28mm diameter as Swifty says). I also believe they sell M30 to Shimano 24mm spindle adapters, but personally I'd buy a Shimano crank and BB and replace the whole thing, and not screw around with adapters

Comment: Also agree on the point about trusting Shimano BBs

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus unfortunately, if the bike takes a PF30 (as it appears), then Shimano doesn't appear to make such a BB. They do make BB86 BBs, which are for a shell with 41mm inside diameter and 86.5mm width. The OP should need a BB that's compatible with the PF30 shell on the outside, and then a 24mm axle on the inside. Many companies make those, but not Shimano (I believe). I agree that Shimano BBs are cheap but trustworthy, and that if one exists for the OP's bottom bracket shell, he will do just fine with it. If it exists.

Comment: @WeiwenNg kudos to you for digging into what BB shall the Roubaix has. PF30 to BB86 adapters definitely exist. Personally what I would look into is a [Hambini Engineering solution](https://www.hambini.com/product/pf30-to-shimano-classic-bottom-bracket/) as these have very good bearing alignment

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus and Weiwen, thanks for the prompts and digging, continued to update. also good suggestions on other solutions if frame isn't threaded

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the incredibly detailed responses, just a few clarifications:

The frame is carbon,
The BB just says M30 on it

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus so i asked on here because i've been watching alot of hambini's videos. I would love to get a bottom bracket from him however I honestly have no idea what spec my frames BB is and since this is my main bike, don't fancy spending the time waiting for him to do a custom job.

Comment: Figuring out what BB you have isn't actually that difficult. If you add a picture to you question of the left hand side of the BB shell showing the cups or bearings as best you can that will allow folks here to rule out  many options

Comment: I'll take a photo now and add it to my question

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus *Personally what I would look into is a Hambini Engineering solution*  I've had good experience with Wheels Mfg adapters, like this: https://wheelsmfg.com/pressfit-30-to-outboard-bottom-bracket-for-24mm-cranks-shimano-black.html

Answer (score 2):

From the picture of the left hand side BB cup comparing it to pictures on the Praxis bottom bracket web page [here](https://praxiscycles.com/bottom-brackets/praxis-m30-bb-options/) I think it's certain you actually have a ISO (aka BSA or English) threaded bottom bracket shell. This can be confirmed by looking at the drive side cup which should have an indicator for the direction to tighten it. Some Praxis BBs fit in press-fit shells but still thread together, the right hand side of these have no tightening direction indicator as they do not rotate in the frame.

If you you want to switch to a Shimano crank this makes it very easy for you. All you need to do is remove the Praxis BB, install a Shimano Hollowtech II Road external bearing BB and any Shimano road crank will drop right in.

You mentioned in comments that you were thinking about a Hambini BB. I don't believe he makes BBs for threaded shells (although I seem to recall he made a custom one for someone and it was featured in a YouTube video). Also, having a threaded shell means you don't need a Hambini BB - the point of having one seems to be to overcome issues with press-fit shell designs.

Comment: Agreed. Happy to be proven wrong about the frame's BB type! In this case, the indicator for which way to tighten the BB does seem to mean it's BSA; their other BBs lack that indicator.

Comment: Thankyou for the great analysis, I did suspect it was a threaded BB however with the lack of specs online and my relative freshness to bike maintenance (I'd only really feel comfortable doing this work on a cheaper bike) I thought i'd ask.

With regards to hambini, that is interesting to know. I didn't realise that was the purpose of his BB's. I wouldn't be able to get one off him at this time anyway as he has stated his supply chain has halted due to his bearing being sourced from italian factories! :S

Comment: @WeiwenNg Another good spot...  only BSA would have a left hand thread indicator on the drive side cup! that might be the simple way to confirm BSA

Comment: Hambini now makes BSA 73mm MTB Shimano, Italian 70mm Shimano and BSA 68mm Shimano threaded BBs.